# Titanium Appcelerator Multi File upload

Tags: file-upload, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

> I'm Developing with Appcelerator SDK 1.6.2 for iOS 4.3

I'm trying to upload multiple files to a server, the problem is the number of files is dynamic and therefore cant be predetermined in the params of the XHR send.

If I pass one file in it works fine but I cant seem to figure out how to pass in many.

I've tried creating an array to hold the media elements but no dice.

```
var media = [];
for(var i = 0; i < sync.images.length; i++){
     media[i] = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(sync.images[i].path).read();
}

xhr.send({
    media: media // no workie
//  media: media[1] workie
});
```

I found this article: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/123794/multiple-file-upload-in-one-request

that assumes the following code should work:

```
 xhr.send({      
     'media[]': imageFile.read(),
     'media[]': imageFile2.read()
 });
```

however i'm uncertain how to obtain this dynamically due to the fact that the number of images transferred can vary

Suggestions would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact problem, and I ended up using the Object.defineProperty method.  Here's how your code could be modified:

Change media into an object instead of an array, then iteratively define properties:

```
var media = {};

for(var i = 0; i < sync.images.length; i++){
    data_blob = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(sync.images[i].path).read();
    data_key = 'image'+i;
    Object.defineProperty(media, data_key, {value: data_blob, enumerable: true});
}

xhr.send(media);
```

Here's the mozilla doc for defineProperty:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FdefineProperty#Adding_properties_and_default_values

Answer (score 1):

You want use the xhr in POST parameter, so `xhr.open("POST", url);`

Second off, try each file in a different object index, for example:

```
{
   file1: imageFile.read(),
   file2: imageFile2.read()
}
```

To grab in PHP, just do `$_FILE['file1'], $_FILE['file2']` ... etc.

Comment: the problem comes from the number of images (and images themselves) being completely dynamic based on the user. How would I set indexes dynamically?

Comment: To future readers -- I had to use the '.toImage()' method as well for this to work

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem and the current marked answer didn't work for me. After some debugging i've found a better solution.

First set the parameters(Note: leave {} if you don't need extra keys / values).

```
var parameters = {'extraKey': 'extraValue'};
```

After that loop through your files and add them to the parameters.

```
for(var i in files) parameters['files[' + i +']'] = files[i];
```

Your parameters will look like this after the loop:

```
{'extraKey':'extraValue', 'file[0]': files[0], 'file[1]': files[1] }
```

Now you can send them like `xhr.send(parameters);`

It's 5 years late but hey I also got here ^^.

Comment: this is a better answer :)  when i wrote mine i didn't know about the syntax for dynamically setting object properties, `obj[keyString] = val` so I used the longwinded `Object.defineProperty`, but it's way less readible